# ip set for smtp mail failed

Tags: email, debian, smtp, postfix

I config smtp server with postfix , and Debian 6.

I set 1 ip from 4 Ips of server for smtp server

> mail.mydomain.com xxx.yyy.zzz.hhh

but when I send mail with smtp server , Destination server give back to me another ip of server.

> Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of root@mail.mydomain.com does
>   not designate xxx.yyy.zzz.jjj as permitted sender)
>   client-ip=xxx.yyy.zzz.jjj; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>
> spf=hardfail (google.com: domain of root@mail.mydomain.com does not
>   designate xxx.yyy.zzz.jjj as permitted sender)
>   smtp.mail=root@mail.mydomain.com

In my Bind configuration and /etc/hosts config this subdomain passed to correct IP . for this IP changed my SPF check give me failed .

what happend when i send mail with smtp server ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the four IPs to DNS record like

```
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:x.x.x.x  -all
```